# MaxScript/Python for Detecting Stretched/Distorted UVs in 3ds Max

Tags: python, 3dsmax, distortion, maxscript, uvw

I need a MaxScript/Python solution to identify objects with UV distortion in 3ds Max, similar to the blue and red colors shown in the UV Editor during area distortion visualization.

Details:

3ds Max Version: 2021
Objective:
Detect and print the names of objects with UV distortion indicated by blue and red colors in the UV Editor.

Your help is greatly appreciated! If you have a script or tips how to write one, please share.

[image: UVW Editor, Area Distortion]

Thank you,

I tried to use the

`Uvwmap() modifier getShowEdgeDistortion() getEdgeDistortionScale()`